# OS X 10.10 File Vault - Restore from Time Machine Backup

Tags: time-machine, filevault

Just for my curiosity and knowledge, from a Software and Hardware stand point prospective, if for any reasons I can not retrieve my Mac File Vault Password and luckily I have a Time Machine Backup (normal backup, not encrypted), after I erase my HDD and reinstall the OS X and restore from Time Machine Backup, does the entire data comes back to my MAC without any issue? Such as: ask me again for my File Vault password?

Thank you so much and have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. Given the scenario you describe (re-install, restore from Time machine backup) the previous Filevault2 password will be gone.

Just make sure you did not exclude important files in `System Preferences` > `Time Machine` > `Options...`